Android build-logic Plugins with conditional configuration. How to pass data to custom convention plugin
My current Android application employs build-logic to define standard plugins
the Room plugin resembles this:-
class AndroidRoomConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        with(target) {
            pluginManager.apply("androidx.room")
            pluginManager.apply("com.google.devtools.ksp")

            extensions.configure<KspExtension> {
                arg("room.generateKotlin", "false")
            }

            extensions.configure<RoomExtension> {
                // The schemas directory contains a schema file for each version of the Room database.
                // This is required to enable Room auto migrations.
                // See https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/AutoMigration.
                schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
            }

            dependencies {
                add("api", libs.findLibrary("room.runtime").get())
                add("api", libs.findLibrary("room.ktx").get())
                add("ksp", libs.findLibrary("room.compiler").get())
            }
        }
    }
}

is there an approach I can take to control when/if the following snippet is added to the gradle build file?
            extensions.configure<RoomExtension> {
                // The schemas directory contains a schema file for each version of the Room database.
                // This is required to enable Room auto migrations.
                // See https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/AutoMigration.
                schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
            }

the reason i require this conditional build configuration is the my Android application has a number of feature modules which each have their own Room schema location and i do not want to add "duplicate"
room {
    schemaDirectory("$projectDir/fetaureOneSchemas")
}

to these modules?
is there anyway I can detect the existence of the room { schemaDirectory() } entry in the existing gradle build file from within my AndroidRoomConventionPlugin and NOT add another...
extensions.configure<RoomExtension> {
                // The schemas directory contains a schema file for each version of the Room database.
                // This is required to enable Room auto migrations.
                // See https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/AutoMigration.
                schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
            }

so as NOT to add another/duplicate room { schemaDirectory() } entry?
